# How does the WTO define what a 'public body' is?

Tags: international

> Washington has repeatedly complained that its judges have adopted a
> narrow definition of what constitutes a ‘public body,’ effectively
> allowing several Chinese companies to receive government subsidies
> against WTO rules.

https://www.worldfinance.com/special-reports/the-wto-is-at-a-crossroads

How does the WTO define what a 'public body' is? And how does it go against what the U.S. would define as a public body? Shouldn't this be clear-cut? I am trying to understand what something that should be straightforward is causing so much disagreement.

Comment: "Shouldn't this be clear-cut? I am trying to understand what something that should be straightforward is causing so much disagreement." China's economy is not so neatly separated into governmental and non-governmental sectors as Western economies. A large share of the economy in China is state owned, or affiliated strongly with state owned enterprises. So, the reality isn't straightforward and that makes a treaty enacted without carefully taking into account these ambiguities in a way that reflects reality hard to apply in the case of China.

Comment: Also, the ambiguity is to some extent intentional. It isn't as if there weren't negotiators in the general agreement on tariffs and trades (GATT) that the WTO implements that weren't aware that this was a potential issue. But the parties decided to gamble on post-diplomacy litigation outcomes rather than write a definition that clearly addressed the concerns in the first place, in part, out of the fear that a clear resolution would prevent a deal from being reached in the first place.